# client_max_body_size directive is not working (?) on Dokku Wordpress app

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dokku

**Problem:**
I've created a Wordpress app on Dokku v0.23.0 (on a DO Ubuntu 18 vps), and I cannot upload any file bigger than 2MB.

**Steps already checked**

- `client_max_body_size 900M;` is set in my `/home/dokku/app-name/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf` and this file is properly imported by `nginx.conf`. I can valide the config by running `dokku nginx:validate-config <app>`. Permissions have been set with `chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/<app>/nginx.conf.d`
- I've also tried to use `dokku nginx:set <app> client-max-body-size 900m` instead of the previous step
- There is a Procfile, loading these values, confirmed by a WP PHP debug plugin

```
upload_max_filesize = 900M
post_max_size = 900M
max_execution_time = 600
memory_limit = 512M
```

- I've restarted nginx and rebuilt my dokku app several times
- I've tried to add the `client_max_body_size` directive in other existing blocks (server/http/location) in the Dokku app nginx config, and in the global Nginx config.
- There is nothing showing up in the nginx error log, when typing `dokku nginx:error-logs <app>`

I don't see what I'm missing here...

Thank you for any help you could provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the php buildpack, you will also need to configure the *buildpacks* nginx (or apache) conf to handle larger files. Consult the [documentation on the php buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings) for more details.

For nginx, it might be something like this:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```